# Debugging typescript files in hybrid angular application in webstorm

Tags: angular, typescript, debugging, angular-hybrid

I have an hybrid application of angular.js and angular 7. Angular.js consist of .js and some .ts files. I have upgraded the angular.js app using the UpgradeModule.
All angular.js src files are listed in angular.json config file, in the scripts array(including path to compiled .ts files but with .js extension).
The problem is that webstorm could'n hit on the breakpoint of .ts files that are listed in the  scripts array of angular.json, therefore there is no way to make a debugger work in WebStorm for this kind of files.

```
"scripts": [
...
"src/legacy/app/js/app.js",
"src/legacy/app/js/common/common.js",
 ...
 "src/legacy/app/services/edit/editService.js" <- here is the .ts file in the original folder (src/legacy/app/services/edit/editService.ts)
...
]
```

Although  the typescript files that are created from angular 7 like (app.component.ts) are being debugged as usual , and hits the breakpoints by WebStorm.

my tsconfig.json have enabled source mapping, also i have tries to enable an inlineSources to true, and   "inlineSourceMap": true, and different combinations of it, but none of it works.

```
"compilerOptions": {
"baseUrl": "./",
"outDir": "build",
"sourceMap": true,
"inlineSources": true,
```

my webStorm debugger settings [debugger settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SsZ15.jpg)

I'm using

```
Angular CLI: 7.3.9
Node: 8.11.4
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 7.2.15
typescript 3.2.4
```

Typescript files that are created from the angular 7 are debug

Maybe someone could suggest how to configure debugger in webstorm for this kind of files ?